# Array object to php using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

How can i send data like this to php using ajax

> ["{"title":"mr","fname":"john","lname":"Annah","oname":"Clement","staffid":"123"}"]

Comment: this is  the output in my javaScript code and i want to send to php through ajax

Comment: plz try to paste your code as well then

Comment: Just use ajax then. What do you expect from us? Please just look up how to do this before asking.

Answer (score 2):

try `json_encode` 
for more refer -
    http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

stringify before sending
Eg :

```
var postData = [
{ "id":"1", "name":"bob"},
{ "id":"2", "name":"jonas"}]
```

this works,

```
$.ajax({
url: Url,
type: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(postData) //stringify is important,
});
```

Comment: Because i want to create object and push to an array and send to php that is why made my output that way. i could have many object of that form in the array

Comment: to get the structure, print_r($_POST) in php page.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like so, using jQuery(which you need to include in your script):

```
 <script>
    var data={};

    data= {
    "title":"mr",
    "fname":"john",
    "lname":"Annah",
    "oname":"Clement",
    "staffid":"123"};

   $.ajax({
            url:"somwhere.php",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"JSON",
            data:data,
            async: true});

    </script>
```

And on the page where you want to catch this data, do it like this:

```
<?php
$title=$_POST['title'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
?>
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", "#your element", function () {
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "your_url",
    data : {"title":"mr","fname":"john","lname":"Annah","oname":"Clement","staffid":"123"},,
    success: function (result) {
        ### your action after ajax
    },
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it in data like this,

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {  title:"mr",fname:"john",lname:"Annah",oname:"Clement",staffid:"123" } ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            //your success code
        }
    });
```